# missing ; after for-loop condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mozilla Firefox error console is telling me over and over again that:

```
missing ; after for-loop condition
```

Here is my JavaScript file (compressed) and I cannot find any error there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('#nav ul li, table tr').mouseover(function(){$(this).addClass('hover')});$('#nav ul li, table tr').mouseout(function(){$(this).removeClass('hover')})});$(document).ready(function(){$('.input-submit').button()});$(document).ready(function(){$('a[rel=external]').click(function(){$(this).attr('target','_top')});$('a[rel=external-new-window]').unbind('click').click(function(){window.open($(this).attr('href'),'','width=800, height=600, scrollbars=1');return false})});$(document).ready(function(){$('.clickable').click(function(){var href=$(this).attr('rel');if(href){window.location=href}})});function browserdetect(){var a=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();if(this.isIE=a.indexOf("msie")>-1)this.ieVer=/msie\s(\d\.\d)/.exec(a)[1],this.quirksMode=!document.compatMode||document.compatMode.indexOf("BackCompat")>-1,this.get_style=function(a,c){if(!(c in a.currentStyle))return"";var d=/^([\d.]+)(\w*)/.exec(a.currentStyle[c]);if(!d)return a.currentStyle[c];if(d[1]==0)return"0";if(d[2]&&d[2]!=="px"){var e=a.style.left,f=a.runtimeStyle.left;a.runtimeStyle.left=a.currentStyle.left;a.style.left=d[1]+d[2];d[0]=a.style.pixelLeft;a.style.left=e;a.runtimeStyle.left=f}return d[0]},this.supportsCorners=this.ieVer>=9;else if(this.ieVer=this.quirksMode=0,this.get_style=function(a,c){c=c.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g,"$1-$2").toLowerCase();return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(a,"").getPropertyValue(c)},this.isSafari=a.indexOf("safari")!=-1,this.isWebKit=a.indexOf("webkit")!=-1,this.isOp="opera"in window)this.supportsCorners=(this.isOp=window.opera.version())>=10.5;else{if(!this.isWebkit&&!(this.isMoz=a.indexOf("firefox")!==-1))for(a=document.childNodes.length;--a>=0;)if("style"in document.childNodes[a]){this.isMoz="MozBorderRadius"in document.childNodes[a].style;break}this.supportsCorners=this.isWebKit||this.isMoz}}var curvyBrowser=new browserdetect;if(curvyBrowser.isIE)try{document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache",!1,!0)}catch(e$$5){}function curvyCnrSpec(a){this.selectorText=a;this.tlR=this.trR=this.blR=this.brR=0;this.tlu=this.tru=this.blu=this.bru="";this.antiAlias=!0}curvyCnrSpec.prototype.setcorner=function(a,b,c,d){a?(a=a.charAt(0)+b.charAt(0),this[a+"R"]=parseInt(c),this[a+"u"]=d):(this.tlR=this.trR=this.blR=this.brR=parseInt(c),this.tlu=this.tru=this.blu=this.bru=d)};curvyCnrSpec.prototype.get=function(a){if(/^(t|b)(l|r)(R|u)$/.test(a))return this[a];if(/^(t|b)(l|r)Ru$/.test(a))return a=a.charAt(0)+a.charAt(1),this[a+"R"]+this[a+"u"];if(/^(t|b)Ru?$/.test(a)){var b=a.charAt(0);b+=this[b+"lR"]>this[b+"rR"]?"l":"r";b=this[b+"R"];a.length===3&&a.charAt(2)==="u"&&(b+=this.u);return b}throw Error("Don't recognize property "+a);};curvyCnrSpec.prototype.radiusdiff=function(a){if(a!=="t"&&a!=="b")throw Error("Param must be 't' or 'b'");return Math.abs(this[a+"lR"]-this[a+"rR"])};curvyCnrSpec.prototype.setfrom=function(a){this.tlu=this.tru=this.blu=this.bru="px";if("tl"in a)this.tlR=a.tl.radius;if("tr"in a)this.trR=a.tr.radius;if("bl"in a)this.blR=a.bl.radius;if("br"in a)this.brR=a.br.radius;if("antiAlias"in a)this.antiAlias=a.antiAlias};curvyCnrSpec.prototype.cloneOn=function(a){var b=["tl","tr","bl","br"],c=0,d,e;for(d in b)if(!isNaN(d)&&(e=this[b[d]+"u"],e!==""&&e!=="px")){c=new curvyCnrSpec;break}if(c){var f,g,k=curvyBrowser.get_style(a,"left");for(d in b)if(!isNaN(d)){f=b[d];e=this[f+"u"];g=this[f+"R"];if(e!=="px"){var l=a.style.left;a.style.left=g+e;g=a.style.pixelLeft;a.style.left=l}c[f+"R"]=g;c[f+"u"]="px"}a.style.left=k}else c=this;return c};curvyCnrSpec.prototype.radiusSum=function(a){if(a!=="t"&&a!=="b")throw Error("Param must be 't' or 'b'");return this[a+"lR"]+this[a+"rR"]};curvyCnrSpec.prototype.radiusCount=function(a){var b=0;this[a+"lR"]&&++b;this[a+"rR"]&&++b;return b};curvyCnrSpec.prototype.cornerNames=function(){var a=[];this.tlR&&a.push("tl");this.trR&&a.push("tr");this.blR&&a.push("bl");this.brR&&a.push("br");return a};function operasheet(a){var a=document.styleSheets.item(a).ownerNode.text,a=a.replace(/\/\*(\n|\r|.)*?\*\//g,""),b=RegExp("^\\s*([\\w.#][-\\w.#, ]+)[\\n\\s]*\\{([^}]+border-((top|bottom)-(left|right)-)?radius[^}]*)\\}","mg"),c;for(this.rules=[];(c=b.exec(a))!==null;){for(var d=RegExp("(..)border-((top|bottom)-(left|right)-)?radius:\\s*([\\d.]+)(in|em|px|ex|pt)","g"),e,f=new curvyCnrSpec(c[1]);(e=d.exec(c[2]))!==null;)e[1]!=="z-"&&f.setcorner(e[3],e[4],e[5],e[6]);this.rules.push(f)}}operasheet.contains_border_radius=function(a){return/border-((top|bottom)-(left|right)-)?radius/.test(document.styleSheets.item(a).ownerNode.text)};function curvyCorners(){var a,b,c,d,e;if(typeof arguments[0]!=="object")throw curvyCorners.newError("First parameter of curvyCorners() must be an object.");if(arguments[0]instanceof curvyCnrSpec){if(d=arguments[0],!d.selectorText&&typeof arguments[1]==="string")d.selectorText=arguments[1]}else{if(typeof arguments[1]!=="object"&&typeof arguments[1]!=="string")throw curvyCorners.newError("Second parameter of curvyCorners() must be an object or a class name.");b=arguments[1];typeof b!=="string"&&(b="");b!==""&&b.charAt(0)!=="."&&"autoPad"in arguments[0]&&(b="."+b);d=new curvyCnrSpec(b);d.setfrom(arguments[0])}if(d.selectorText){e=0;var f=d.selectorText.replace(/\s+$/,"").split(/,\s*/);c=[];for(a=0;a<f.length;++a){if((b=f[a].lastIndexOf("#"))!==-1)f[a]=f[a].substr(b);c=c.concat(curvyCorners.getElementsBySelector(f[a].split(/\s+/)))}}else e=1,c=arguments;a=e;for(b=c.length;a<b;++a)if(e=c[a],f=!1,e.className?(f=e.className.indexOf("curvyIgnore")!==-1)||(e.className+=" curvyIgnore"):e.className="curvyIgnore",!f){if(e.className.indexOf("curvyRedraw")!==-1){if(typeof curvyCorners.redrawList==="undefined")curvyCorners.redrawList=[];curvyCorners.redrawList.push({node:e,spec:d,copy:e.cloneNode(!1)})}(new curvyObject(d,e)).applyCorners()}}curvyCorners.prototype.applyCornersToAll=function(){throw curvyCorners.newError("This function is now redundant. Just call curvyCorners(). See documentation.");};curvyCorners.redraw=function(){if(!curvyBrowser.supportsCorners){if(!curvyCorners.redrawList)throw curvyCorners.newError("curvyCorners.redraw() has nothing to redraw.");var a=curvyCorners.block_redraw;curvyCorners.block_redraw=!0;for(var b in curvyCorners.redrawList)if(!isNaN(b)){var c=curvyCorners.redrawList[b];if(c.node.clientWidth){for(var d=c.copy.cloneNode(!1),e=c.node.firstChild;e!==null;e=e.nextSibling)if(e.className.indexOf("autoPadDiv")!==-1)break;if(!e){curvyCorners.alert("Couldn't find autoPad DIV");break}c.node.parentNode.replaceChild(d,c.node);for(var f=e.getElementsByTagName("script"),g=f.length-1;g>=0;--g)f[g].parentNode.removeChild(f[g]);for(;e.firstChild;)d.appendChild(e.removeChild(e.firstChild));c=new curvyObject(c.spec,c.node=d);c.applyCorners()}}curvyCorners.block_redraw=a}};curvyCorners.adjust=function(a,b,c){if(!curvyBrowser.supportsCorners){if(!curvyCorners.redrawList)throw curvyCorners.newError("curvyCorners.adjust() has nothing to adjust.");var d,e=curvyCorners.redrawList.length;for(d=0;d<e;++d)if(curvyCorners.redrawList[d].node===a)break;if(d===e)throw curvyCorners.newError("Object not redrawable");a=curvyCorners.redrawList[d].copy}b.indexOf(".")===-1?a[b]=c:eval("obj."+b+"='"+c+"'")};curvyCorners.handleWinResize=function(){curvyCorners.block_redraw||curvyCorners.redraw()};curvyCorners.setWinResize=function(a){curvyCorners.block_redraw=!a};curvyCorners.newError=function(a){return Error("curvyCorners Error:\n"+a)};curvyCorners.alert=function(a){(typeof curvyCornersVerbose==="undefined"||curvyCornersVerbose)&&alert(a)};function curvyObject(a,b){var c;this.box=b;this.settings=a;this.topContainer=this.bottomContainer=this.shell=c=null;var d=this.box.clientWidth;if("canHaveChildren"in this.box&&!this.box.canHaveChildren||this.box.tagName==="TABLE")throw Error(this.errmsg("You cannot apply corners to "+this.box.tagName+" elements.","Error"));if(!d&&curvyBrowser.isIE)this.box.style.zoom=1,d=this.box.clientWidth;if(!d&&curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"display")==="inline")this.box.style.display="inline-block",curvyCorners.alert(this.errmsg("Converting inline element to inline-block","warning")),d=this.box.clientWidth;if(!d){if(!this.box.parentNode)throw this.newError("box has no parent!");for(c=this.box;c=c.parentNode){if(!c||c.tagName==="BODY"){this.applyCorners=function(){};curvyCorners.alert(this.errmsg("zero-width box with no accountable parent","warning"));return}if(curvyBrowser.get_style(c,"display")==="none")break}var e=c.style.display;c.style.display="block";d=this.box.clientWidth}if(d){a instanceof curvyCnrSpec?this.spec=a.cloneOn(this.box):(this.spec=new curvyCnrSpec(""),this.spec.setfrom(this.settings));var f=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderTopWidth"),g=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderBottomWidth"),k=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderLeftWidth"),l=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderRightWidth"),s=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderTopColor"),y=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderBottomColor"),q=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderLeftColor"),o=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderRightColor"),E=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderTopStyle"),F=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderBottomStyle"),G=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderLeftStyle"),H=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"borderRightStyle"),C=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"backgroundColor"),D=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"backgroundImage"),I=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"backgroundRepeat"),p,t;this.box.currentStyle&&this.box.currentStyle.backgroundPositionX?(p=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"backgroundPositionX"),t=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"backgroundPositionY")):(p=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"backgroundPosition"),p=p.split(" "),t=p.length===2?p[1]:0,p=p[0]);var J=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"position"),K=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"paddingTop"),L=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"paddingBottom"),M=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"paddingLeft"),N=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"paddingRight"),w=curvyBrowser.ieVer>7?curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"filter"):null,x=this.spec.get("tR"),z=this.spec.get("bR"),u=function(a){if(typeof a==="number")return a;if(typeof a!=="string")throw Error("unexpected styleToNPx type "+typeof a);var c=/^[-\d.]([a-z]+)$/.exec(a);if(c&&c[1]!="px")throw Error("Unexpected unit "+c[1]);if(isNaN(a=parseInt(a)))a=0;return a};try{this.borderWidth=u(f),this.borderWidthB=u(g),this.borderWidthL=u(k),this.borderWidthR=u(l),this.boxColour=curvyObject.format_colour(C),this.topPadding=u(K),this.bottomPadding=u(L),this.leftPadding=u(M),this.rightPadding=u(N),this.boxWidth=d,this.boxHeight=this.box.clientHeight,this.borderColour=curvyObject.format_colour(s),this.borderColourB=curvyObject.format_colour(y),this.borderColourL=curvyObject.format_colour(q),this.borderColourR=curvyObject.format_colour(o),this.borderString=this.borderWidth+"px "+E+" "+this.borderColour,this.borderStringB=this.borderWidthB+"px "+F+" "+this.borderColourB,this.borderStringL=this.borderWidthL+"px "+G+" "+this.borderColourL,this.borderStringR=this.borderWidthR+"px "+H+" "+this.borderColourR,this.backgroundImage=D!="none"?D:"",this.backgroundRepeat=I}catch(O){throw this.newError(O.message);}var A=this.boxHeight,B=d;if(curvyBrowser.isOp){var v;p=u(p);t=u(t);p&&(v=B+this.borderWidthL+this.borderWidthR,p>v&&(p=v),p=v/p*100+"%");t&&(v=A+this.borderWidth+this.borderWidthB,t>v&&(t=v),t=v/t*100+"%")}curvyBrowser.quirksMode||(this.boxWidth-=this.leftPadding+this.rightPadding,this.boxHeight-=this.topPadding+this.bottomPadding);this.contentContainer=document.createElement("div");if(w)this.contentContainer.style.filter=w;for(;this.box.firstChild;)this.contentContainer.appendChild(this.box.removeChild(this.box.firstChild));if(J!="absolute")this.box.style.position="relative";this.box.style.padding="0";this.box.style.border=this.box.style.backgroundImage="none";this.box.style.backgroundColor="transparent";this.box.style.width=B+this.borderWidthL+this.borderWidthR+"px";this.box.style.height=A+this.borderWidth+this.borderWidthB+"px";var i=document.createElement("div");i.style.position="absolute";if(w)i.style.filter=w;i.style.width=curvyBrowser.quirksMode?B+this.borderWidthL+this.borderWidthR+"px":B+"px";i.style.height=A+this.borderWidth+this.borderWidthB-x-z<=0?"0":A+this.borderWidth+this.borderWidthB-x-z+"px";i.style.padding="0";i.style.top=x+"px";i.style.left="0";if(this.borderWidthL)i.style.borderLeft=this.borderStringL;if(this.borderWidth&&!x)i.style.borderTop=this.borderString;if(this.borderWidthR)i.style.borderRight=this.borderStringR;if(this.borderWidthB&&!z)i.style.borderBottom=this.borderStringB;i.style.backgroundColor=C;i.style.backgroundImage=this.backgroundImage;i.style.backgroundRepeat=this.backgroundRepeat;i.style.direction="ltr";this.shell=this.box.appendChild(i);d=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.shell,"width");if(d===""||d==="auto"||d.indexOf("%")!==-1)throw this.newError("Shell width is "+d);this.boxWidth=d!==""&&d!="auto"&&d.indexOf("%")==-1?parseInt(d):this.shell.clientWidth;this.applyCorners=function(){this.backgroundPosX=this.backgroundPosY=0;if(this.backgroundObject){var a=function(a,c,b){if(a===0)return 0;if(a==="right"||a==="bottom")return b-c;if(a==="center")return(b-c)/2;if(a.indexOf("%")>0)return(b-c)*100/parseInt(a);return u(a)};this.backgroundPosX=a(p,this.backgroundObject.width,B);this.backgroundPosY=a(t,this.backgroundObject.height,A)}else if(this.backgroundImage)this.backgroundPosX=u(p),this.backgroundPosY=u(t);if(x)i=document.createElement("div"),i.style.width=this.boxWidth+"px",i.style.fontSize="1px",i.style.overflow="hidden",i.style.position="absolute",i.style.paddingLeft=this.borderWidth+"px",i.style.paddingRight=this.borderWidth+"px",i.style.height=x+"px",i.style.top=-x+"px",i.style.left=-this.borderWidthL+"px",this.topContainer=this.shell.appendChild(i);if(z)i=document.createElement("div"),i.style.width=this.boxWidth+"px",i.style.fontSize="1px",i.style.overflow="hidden",i.style.position="absolute",i.style.paddingLeft=this.borderWidthB+"px",i.style.paddingRight=this.borderWidthB+"px",i.style.height=z+"px",i.style.bottom=-z+"px",i.style.left=-this.borderWidthL+"px",this.bottomContainer=this.shell.appendChild(i);var a=this.spec.cornerNames(),b;for(b in a)if(!isNaN(b)){var d=a[b],f=this.spec[d+"R"],k,g,l;d=="tr"||d=="tl"?(k=this.borderColour,l=this.borderWidth):(k=this.borderColourB,l=this.borderWidthB);g=f-l;var n=document.createElement("div");n.style.height=this.spec.get(d+"Ru");n.style.width=this.spec.get(d+"Ru");n.style.position="absolute";n.style.fontSize="1px";n.style.overflow="hidden";var m,j,o,s=w?parseInt(/alpha\(opacity.(\d+)\)/.exec(w)[1]):100;for(m=0;m<f;++m){var y=m+1>=g?-1:Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(g,2)-Math.pow(m+1,2)))-1;if(g!=f)var h=m>=g?-1:Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(g,2)-Math.pow(m,2))),q=m+1>=f?-1:Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(f,2)-Math.pow(m+1,2)))-1;var C=m>=f?-1:Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(f,2)-Math.pow(m,2)));y>-1&&this.drawPixel(m,0,this.boxColour,s,y+1,n,!0,f);if(g!=f)if(this.spec.antiAlias){for(j=y+1;j<h;++j)this.backgroundImage!==""?(o=curvyObject.pixelFraction(m,j,g)*100,this.drawPixel(m,j,k,s,1,n,o>=30,f)):this.boxColour!=="transparent"?(o=curvyObject.BlendColour(this.boxColour,k,curvyObject.pixelFraction(m,j,g)),this.drawPixel(m,j,o,s,1,n,!1,f)):this.drawPixel(m,j,k,s>>1,1,n,!1,f);q>=h&&(h==-1&&(h=0),this.drawPixel(m,h,k,s,q-h+1,n,!1,0));o=k;j=q}else q>y&&this.drawPixel(m,y+1,k,s,q-y,n,!1,0);else o=this.boxColour,j=y;if(this.spec.antiAlias&&this.boxColour!=="transparent")for(;++j<C;)this.drawPixel(m,j,o,curvyObject.pixelFraction(m,j,f)*s,1,n,l<=0,f)}v=0;for(k=n.childNodes.length;v<k;++v){g=n.childNodes[v];l=parseInt(g.style.top);m=parseInt(g.style.left);s=parseInt(g.style.height);if(d=="tl"||d=="bl")g.style.left=f-m-1+"px";if(d=="tr"||d=="tl")g.style.top=f-s-l+"px";g.style.backgroundRepeat=this.backgroundRepeat;if(this.backgroundImage)switch(d){case"tr":g.style.backgroundPosition=this.backgroundPosX-this.borderWidthL+f-B-m+"px "+(this.backgroundPosY+s+l+this.borderWidth-f)+"px";break;case"tl":g.style.backgroundPosition=this.backgroundPosX-f+m+1+this.borderWidthL+"px "+(this.backgroundPosY-f+s+l+this.borderWidth)+"px";break;case"bl":g.style.backgroundPosition=this.backgroundPosX-f+m+1+this.borderWidthL+"px "+(this.backgroundPosY-A-this.borderWidth+(curvyBrowser.quirksMode?l:-l)+f)+"px";break;case"br":g.style.backgroundPosition=curvyBrowser.quirksMode?this.backgroundPosX-this.borderWidthL-B+f-m+"px "+(this.backgroundPosY-A-this.borderWidth+l+f)+"px":this.backgroundPosX-this.borderWidthL-B+f-m+"px "+(this.backgroundPosY-A-this.borderWidth+f-l)+"px"}}switch(d){case"tl":n.style.top=n.style.left="0";this.topContainer.appendChild(n);break;case"tr":n.style.top=n.style.right="0";this.topContainer.appendChild(n);break;case"bl":n.style.bottom=n.style.left="0";this.bottomContainer.appendChild(n);break;case"br":n.style.bottom=n.style.right="0",this.bottomContainer.appendChild(n)}}b={t:this.spec.radiusdiff("t"),b:this.spec.radiusdiff("b")};for(var r in b)if(typeof r!=="function"&&this.spec.get(r+"R")){if(b[r]){j=this.spec[r+"lR"]<this.spec[r+"rR"]?r+"l":r+"r";h=document.createElement("div");h.style.height=b[r]+"px";h.style.width=this.spec.get(j+"Ru");h.style.position="absolute";h.style.fontSize="1px";h.style.overflow="hidden";h.style.backgroundColor=this.boxColour;if(w)h.style.filter=w;h.style.backgroundImage=this.backgroundImage;h.style.backgroundRepeat=this.backgroundRepeat;switch(j){case"tl":h.style.bottom=h.style.left="0";h.style.borderLeft=this.borderStringL;h.style.backgroundPosition=this.backgroundPosX+"px "+(this.borderWidth+this.backgroundPosY-this.spec.tlR)+"px";this.topContainer.appendChild(h);break;case"tr":h.style.bottom=h.style.right="0";h.style.borderRight=this.borderStringR;h.style.backgroundPosition=this.backgroundPosX-this.boxWidth+this.spec.trR+"px "+(this.borderWidth+this.backgroundPosY-this.spec.trR)+"px";this.topContainer.appendChild(h);break;case"bl":h.style.top=h.style.left="0";h.style.borderLeft=this.borderStringL;h.style.backgroundPosition=this.backgroundPosX+"px "+(this.backgroundPosY-this.borderWidth-this.boxHeight+b[r]+this.spec.blR)+"px";this.bottomContainer.appendChild(h);break;case"br":h.style.top=h.style.right="0",h.style.borderRight=this.borderStringR,h.style.backgroundPosition=this.borderWidthL+this.backgroundPosX-this.boxWidth+this.spec.brR+"px "+(this.backgroundPosY-this.borderWidth-this.boxHeight+b[r]+this.spec.brR)+"px",this.bottomContainer.appendChild(h)}}j=document.createElement("div");if(w)j.style.filter=w;j.style.position="relative";j.style.fontSize="1px";j.style.overflow="hidden";j.style.width=this.fillerWidth(r);j.style.backgroundColor=this.boxColour;j.style.backgroundImage=this.backgroundImage;j.style.backgroundRepeat=this.backgroundRepeat;switch(r){case"t":if(this.topContainer){j.style.height=curvyBrowser.quirksMode?100+x+"px":100+x-this.borderWidth+"px";j.style.marginLeft=this.spec.tlR?this.spec.tlR-this.borderWidthL+"px":"0";j.style.borderTop=this.borderString;if(this.backgroundImage)h=this.spec.tlR?this.borderWidthL+this.backgroundPosX-this.spec.tlR+"px ":this.backgroundPosX+"px ",j.style.backgroundPosition=h+this.backgroundPosY+"px",this.shell.style.backgroundPosition=this.backgroundPosX+"px "+(this.backgroundPosY-x+this.borderWidthL)+"px";this.topContainer.appendChild(j)}break;case"b":if(this.bottomContainer){j.style.height=curvyBrowser.quirksMode?z+"px":z-this.borderWidthB+"px";j.style.marginLeft=this.spec.blR?this.spec.blR-this.borderWidthL+"px":"0";j.style.borderBottom=this.borderStringB;if(this.backgroundImage)h=this.spec.blR?this.backgroundPosX+this.borderWidthL-this.spec.blR+"px ":this.backgroundPosX+"px ",j.style.backgroundPosition=h+(this.backgroundPosY-A-this.borderWidth+z)+"px";this.bottomContainer.appendChild(j)}}}this.contentContainer.style.position="absolute";this.contentContainer.className="autoPadDiv";this.contentContainer.style.left=this.borderWidthL+"px";this.contentContainer.style.paddingTop=this.topPadding+"px";this.contentContainer.style.top=this.borderWidth+"px";this.contentContainer.style.paddingLeft=this.leftPadding+"px";this.contentContainer.style.paddingRight=this.rightPadding+"px";r=B;curvyBrowser.quirksMode||(r-=this.leftPadding+this.rightPadding);this.contentContainer.style.width=r+"px";this.contentContainer.style.textAlign=curvyBrowser.get_style(this.box,"textAlign");this.box.style.textAlign="left";this.box.appendChild(this.contentContainer);if(c)c.style.display=e};if(this.backgroundImage&&(p=this.backgroundCheck(p),t=this.backgroundCheck(t),this.backgroundObject))this.backgroundObject.holdingElement=this,this.dispatch=this.applyCorners,this.applyCorners=function(){this.backgroundObject.complete?this.dispatch():this.backgroundObject.onload=new Function("curvyObject.dispatch(this.holdingElement);")}}else curvyCorners.alert(this.errmsg("zero-width box, cannot display","error")),this.applyCorners=function(){}}curvyObject.prototype.backgroundCheck=function(a){if(a==="top"||a==="left"||parseInt(a)===0)return 0;if(!/^[-\d.]+px$/.test(a)&&!this.backgroundObject)this.backgroundObject=new Image,this.backgroundObject.src=function(a){var c=/url\("?([^'"]+)"?\)/.exec(a);return c?c[1]:a}(this.backgroundImage);return a};curvyObject.dispatch=function(a){if("dispatch"in a)a.dispatch();else throw a.newError("No dispatch function");};curvyObject.prototype.drawPixel=function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,k){var l=document.createElement("div");l.style.height=e+"px";l.style.width="1px";l.style.position="absolute";l.style.fontSize="1px";l.style.overflow="hidden";e=this.spec.get("tR");l.style.backgroundColor=c;if(g&&this.backgroundImage!=="")l.style.backgroundImage=this.backgroundImage,l.style.backgroundPosition="-"+(this.boxWidth-(k-a)+this.borderWidth)+"px -"+(this.boxHeight+e+b-this.borderWidth)+"px";d!=100&&curvyObject.setOpacity(l,d);l.style.top=b+"px";l.style.left=a+"px";f.appendChild(l)};curvyObject.prototype.fillerWidth=function(a){var b;b=curvyBrowser.quirksMode?0:this.spec.radiusCount(a)*this.borderWidthL;if((a=this.boxWidth-this.spec.radiusSum(a)+b)<0)throw this.newError("Radius exceeds box width");return a+"px"};curvyObject.prototype.errmsg=function(a,b){var c="\ntag: "+this.box.tagName;this.box.id&&(c+="\nid: "+this.box.id);this.box.className&&(c+="\nclass: "+this.box.className);var d;(d=this.box.parentNode)===null?c+="\n(box has no parent)":(c+="\nParent tag: "+d.tagName,d.id&&(c+="\nParent ID: "+d.id),d.className&&(c+="\nParent class: "+d.className));b===void 0&&(b="warning");return"curvyObject "+b+":\n"+a+c};curvyObject.prototype.newError=function(a){return Error(this.errmsg(a,"exception"))};curvyObject.IntToHex=function(a){var b=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"];return b[a>>>4]+""+b[a&15]};curvyObject.BlendColour=function(a,b,c){if(a==="transparent"||b==="transparent")throw this.newError("Cannot blend with transparent");a.charAt(0)!=="#"&&(a=curvyObject.format_colour(a));b.charAt(0)!=="#"&&(b=curvyObject.format_colour(b));var d=parseInt(a.substr(1,2),16),e=parseInt(a.substr(3,2),16),a=parseInt(a.substr(5,2),16),f=parseInt(b.substr(1,2),16),g=parseInt(b.substr(3,2),16),b=parseInt(b.substr(5,2),16);if(c>1||c<0)c=1;d=Math.round(d*c+f*(1-c));d>255&&(d=255);d<0&&(d=0);e=Math.round(e*c+g*(1-c));e>255&&(e=255);e<0&&(e=0);c=Math.round(a*c+b*(1-c));c>255&&(c=255);c<0&&(c=0);return"#"+curvyObject.IntToHex(d)+curvyObject.IntToHex(e)+curvyObject.IntToHex(c)};curvyObject.pixelFraction=function(a,b,c){c*=c;var d=Array(2),e=Array(2),f=0,g="",k=Math.sqrt(c-Math.pow(a,2));k>=b&&k<b+1&&(g="Left",d[f]=0,e[f]=k-b,++f);k=Math.sqrt(c-Math.pow(b+1,2));k>=a&&k<a+1&&(g+="Top",d[f]=k-a,e[f]=1,++f);k=Math.sqrt(c-Math.pow(a+1,2));k>=b&&k<b+1&&(g+="Right",d[f]=1,e[f]=k-b,++f);k=Math.sqrt(c-Math.pow(b,2));k>=a&&k<a+1&&(g+="Bottom",d[f]=k-a,e[f]=0);switch(g){case"LeftRight":a=Math.min(e[0],e[1])+(Math.max(e[0],e[1])-Math.min(e[0],e[1]))/2;break;case"TopRight":a=1-(1-d[0])*(1-e[1])/2;break;case"TopBottom":a=Math.min(d[0],d[1])+(Math.max(d[0],d[1])-Math.min(d[0],d[1]))/2;break;case"LeftBottom":a=e[0]*d[1]/2;break;default:a=1}return a};curvyObject.rgb2Array=function(a){return a.substring(4,a.indexOf(")")).split(/,\s*/)};curvyObject.rgb2Hex=function(a){try{var b=curvyObject.rgb2Array(a),c=parseInt(b[0]),d=parseInt(b[1]),e=parseInt(b[2]),f="#"+curvyObject.IntToHex(c)+curvyObject.IntToHex(d)+curvyObject.IntToHex(e)}catch(g){throw a="getMessage"in g?g.getMessage():g.message,Error("Error ("+a+") converting RGB value to Hex in rgb2Hex");}return f};curvyObject.setOpacity=function(a,b){b=b==100?99.999:b;if(curvyBrowser.isSafari&&a.tagName!="IFRAME"){var c=curvyObject.rgb2Array(a.style.backgroundColor),d=parseInt(c[0]),e=parseInt(c[1]),c=parseInt(c[2]);a.style.backgroundColor="rgba("+d+", "+e+", "+c+", "+b/100+")"}else if(typeof a.style.opacity!=="undefined")a.style.opacity=b/100;else if(typeof a.style.MozOpacity!=="undefined")a.style.MozOpacity=b/100;else if(typeof a.style.filter!=="undefined")a.style.filter="alpha(opacity="+b+")";else if(typeof a.style.KHTMLOpacity!=="undefined")a.style.KHTMLOpacity=b/100};curvyCorners.addEvent=function(a,b,c,d){if(a.addEventListener)return a.addEventListener(b,c,d),!0;if(a.attachEvent)return a.attachEvent("on"+b,c);a["on"+b]=c;return!1};if(typeof addEvent==="undefined")addEvent=curvyCorners.addEvent;curvyObject.getComputedColour=function(a){var b=document.createElement("DIV");b.style.backgroundColor=a;document.body.appendChild(b);if(window.getComputedStyle)return a=document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(b,null).getPropertyValue("background-color"),b.parentNode.removeChild(b),a.substr(0,3)==="rgb"&&(a=curvyObject.rgb2Hex(a)),a;else{var c=document.body.createTextRange();c.moveToElementText(b);c.execCommand("ForeColor",!1,a);a=c.queryCommandValue("ForeColor");a="rgb("+(a&255)+", "+((a&65280)>>8)+", "+((a&16711680)>>16)+")";b.parentNode.removeChild(b);return curvyObject.rgb2Hex(a)}};curvyObject.format_colour=function(a){a!==""&&a!=="transparent"&&(a.substr(0,3)==="rgb"?a=curvyObject.rgb2Hex(a):a.charAt(0)!=="#"?a=curvyObject.getComputedColour(a):a.length===4&&(a="#"+a.charAt(1)+a.charAt(1)+a.charAt(2)+a.charAt(2)+a.charAt(3)+a.charAt(3)));return a};curvyCorners.getElementsByClass=function(a,b){var c=[];b===void 0&&(b=document);var a=a.split("."),d="*";a.length===1?(d=a[0],a=!1):(a[0]&&(d=a[0]),a=a[1]);var e,f;if(d.charAt(0)==="#")(e=document.getElementById(d.substr(1)))&&c.push(e);else if(e=b.getElementsByTagName(d),f=e.length,a)for(var g=RegExp("(^|\\s)"+a+"(\\s|$)"),d=0;d<f;++d)g.test(e[d].className)&&c.push(e[d]);else for(d=0;d<f;++d)c.push(e[d]);return c};curvyCorners.getElementsBySelector=function(a,b){var c;c=a[0];b===void 0&&(b=document);if(c.indexOf("#")===-1)c=curvyCorners.getElementsByClass(c,b);else{c=b.getElementById(c.substr(1));if(!c)return[];c=[c]}if(a.length>1){for(var d=[],e=c.length;--e>=0;)d=d.concat(curvyCorners.getElementsBySelector(a.slice(1),c[e]));c=d}return c};if(curvyBrowser.supportsCorners){var curvyCornersNoAutoScan=!0;curvyCorners.init=function(){}}else curvyCorners.scanStyles=function(){function a(a){if(!parseInt(a))return"px";return/^[\d.]+(\w+)$/.exec(a)[1]}var b,c,d;if(curvyBrowser.isIE){var e=function(c){var b=c.style,d,e,f,q;curvyBrowser.ieVer>6?(d=b["-moz-border-radius"]||0,e=b["-moz-border-radius-topright"]||0,f=b["-moz-border-radius-topleft"]||0,q=b["-moz-border-radius-bottomright"]||0,b=b["-moz-border-radius-bottomleft"]||0):(d=b["moz-border-radius"]||0,e=b["moz-border-radius-topright"]||0,f=b["moz-border-radius-topleft"]||0,q=b["moz-border-radius-bottomright"]||0,b=b["moz-border-radius-bottomleft"]||0);if(d){var o=d.split("/"),o=o[0].split(/\s+/);o[o.length-1]===""&&o.pop();switch(o.length){case 3:f=o[0];e=b=o[1];q=o[2];d=!1;break;case 2:f=q=o[0],e=b=o[1],d=!1;case 1:break;case 4:f=o[0];e=o[1];q=o[2];b=o[3];d=!1;break;default:curvyCorners.alert("Illegal corners specification: "+d)}}if(d||f||e||q||b)c=new curvyCnrSpec(c.selectorText),d?c.setcorner(null,null,parseInt(d),a(d)):(e&&c.setcorner("t","r",parseInt(e),a(e)),f&&c.setcorner("t","l",parseInt(f),a(f)),b&&c.setcorner("b","l",parseInt(b),a(b)),q&&c.setcorner("b","r",parseInt(q),a(q))),curvyCorners(c)};for(b=0;b<document.styleSheets.length;++b)try{if(document.styleSheets[b].imports)for(c=0;c<document.styleSheets[b].imports.length;++c)for(d=0;d<document.styleSheets[b].imports[c].rules.length;++d)e(document.styleSheets[b].imports[c].rules[d]);for(c=0;c<document.styleSheets[b].rules.length;++c)e(document.styleSheets[b].rules[c])}catch(f){typeof curvyCornersVerbose!=="undefined"&&curvyCornersVerbose&&alert(f.message+" - ignored")}}else if(curvyBrowser.isOp)for(b=0;b<document.styleSheets.length;++b){if(operasheet.contains_border_radius(b))for(c in d=new operasheet(b),d.rules)isNaN(c)||curvyCorners(d.rules[c])}else curvyCorners.alert("Scanstyles does nothing in Webkit/Firefox/Opera")},curvyCorners.init=function(){if(!arguments.callee.done){arguments.callee.done=!0;if(curvyBrowser.isWebKit&&curvyCorners.init.timer)clearInterval(curvyCorners.init.timer),curvyCorners.init.timer=null;curvyCorners.scanStyles()}};if(typeof curvyCornersNoAutoScan==="undefined"||curvyCornersNoAutoScan===!1)curvyBrowser.isOp?document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",curvyCorners.init,!1):curvyCorners.addEvent(window,"load",curvyCorners.init,!1);
```

Perhaps the compression messed something up? I just opened the uncompressed code in Eclipse and there are no errors.

Comment: Off topic: I notice you're using Curvy Corners. I'd always recommend using CSS3 `border-radius` for this, plus CSS3Pie in your stylesheet to support older versions of IE.

Comment: "I cannot find any error there:" - Neither can (or will) I! This is a joke, right? Format your code! Who's supposed to read this all-in-one-line MONSTER?

Comment: @Mörre  : http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: So it is MY job now to work around artificial obstacles to be able to answer these questions here?

Comment: @Mörre: The error IS caused by compression, if there was no compression there should be NO error. The OP has a GOOD point here (even if it looks ugly), If it is not your job, please stay away of the question.

Comment: @Morre Firstly, the formatted code has no error. Error is caused by compression. Secondly, SO char limit would not allow me to post the formatted version anyways.

Comment: @Richard Knop: How about letting those decide whom you ask - OR tell us "I asked jslint and there is no error in the code". As for size, ever heard about gist.github.com

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: It seems quite a few people share my view. How about YOU stay away from commenting what *I* do if you don't like it? It works both ways, you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **are many locations** in your code where you did not use the `;` [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) reports about 10, **this is killing for compression**. those errors probably chain react to a mis-interpretation of the file by the javascript engine.

Comment: What compresor should I use? I already tried three different ones and they all compress for loops like that.

Comment: Validate your code first with jshint or jsLint, then fix the errors and THEN compress again ;)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of opening your uncompressed code in Eclipse, open it in [JSHint](http://jshint.com), fix the errors and I'll bet your problem goes away. Make sure you configure your options to indicate you're using jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I use it all the time, rather I use JSLint though which is much more strict. Either way OP was writing sloppy code, relying on the interpreter to do semi-colon insertions and then minifying it which resulted in it breaking.

Answer (score 3):

The code is virtually un-readable in the compressed format, but there are some `for()` loops without the two semicolons.

If you search for the word `for(` in the code, you should find them. One is about a third of the way through, and reads `for(c=this.box;c=c.parentNode)`.

I didn't have time to keep searching, but I suspect there are more.

If the code is working prior to being compressed then I suspect you're correct about the compressor being faulty. What compressor did you use?

Answer (score 1):

In `for(var d=RegExp("(..)border-((top|bottom)-(left|right)-)?radius:\\s*([\\d.]+)(in|em|px|ex|pt)","g"),e,f=new curvyCnrSpec(c[1]);(e=d.exec(c[2]))!==null;)e[1]!=="z-"&&f.setcorner(e[3],e[4],e[5],e[6])`
The semicolon after `null` should come after the closing parenthesis. This would be a lot easier to spot if your code was not formatted all on one line.

EDIT: Disregard this, it is totally wrong.

Comment: I would if SO character limit would allow me to.

Comment: That's not it. The `)` after `(e=d.exec(c[2]))!==null;` is the close of the `for`. The `;` is the second semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

With same problem, found a comma instead of semi-colon.
for(i = 0, i < x.length; i++)